# Adding chapter to table of contents without numbering and without removing it from automark?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, numbering, chapters

I know similiar questions have been posted but i couldn't find one that explicitly solved my problem. I added a chapter called "Abstract" before the actual start of my master's thesis that starts with "Introduction". I want to have the abstract excluded from the numbering of the chapters but still have it added to the table of contents. I am using the report document class. Based on the answers of other questions i succeeded in doing so by using

```
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
```

Unfortunately this resulted in a new problem i couldn't fix yet. I am using the following code to display the current chapter title in the top right corner of each page after the initital chapter page:

```
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\automark{chapter}
```

Using \chapter*{Abstract} seems to have also excluded the abstract from that. That means the second page of the abstract currently has "List of Tables" displayed in the top right corner, probably because the abstract chapter hasn't been picked up by the previous command.

So I would be very thankful for a solution to either

a) somehow allow the normal use of \chapter{Abstract} while having it displayed in the table of contents without a number and thus leaving the title in the header intact

or

b) allow \chapter*{Abstract} to be picked up by the header command as well or a hard coded workaround to fix the title in the header for exclusively this page.

Thanks in advance,

Benjamin

Comment: Welcometo TeX.SE!

Comment: Try `\chapter*{Abstract}
\markboth{Abstract}{Abstract}`

Comment: Thank you very much Pieter! That solved the problem.